# How to make animation when I hover img tag to show text under him

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make animation when I hover img tag to show text under him (must be animate showing text, slowly) but that is not all It must also move other content down when text show and to return when text is gone (when is not hover). Very Important showing text must be animate and going back.
I don't care if it works with jq or css or both just need work. I am a beginner so maybe it is obviously I just don't see it.

HTML:

```
    <div class="first-block"></div>
    <div class="secend-block">
        <div class="box">
            <img src="/Test/beach.jpg" alt="beach" width="200px" height="200px">
            <p>asdasdasssssssssssssssssssssss
                asdddddddddddddddddddddd
                asdaaaadsssssssssssadsadsdasd
                adsssssssssssssssssadsadsadsa
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="third-block">
        <h1>some content</h1>
        <h1>some content</h1>
        <h1>some content</h1>
        <h1>some content</h1>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .first-block{
    width: 99%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #f10000;
}

.secend-block{
    width: 99%;
    height: auto;
    background: #ffffff;

}

.secend-block .box{
    width: 200px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.secend-block .box p{
    display: none;
}

.third-block{
    width: 99%;
    height: auto;
    background: #4400ff;
}
```

Comment: Check the css:hover

Comment: I tried but can't make an animation to slowly show text

Comment: Why it’s not in you code ?

Comment: I delete that because it is working well but without animation, I make like when it is hovering just display: block; but there is no animation I don't know how to do that. If I make animation in some cases my third content doesn't moving down. I just don't know how to make it with the animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.class:hover`

Basically, when `.image` is hovered, we want to change the styles of `.text`. The CSS query `.image:hover + .text` selects the `.text` the element where there is an image that is being hovered right before it.

```css
.image {
  width: 250px;
}

.text {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  transition: max-height 1s;
}

.image:hover + .text {
  max-height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg" />
  <p class="text">This is some text</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg" />
  <p class="text">This is some text</p>
</div>
```